# How do I get the avro code generator to use a different type, other than the predefined primitive and complex types in schema?

Tags: avro

I have a simple avro schema that looks like this:

```
{
        "type": "record",
        "name": "transaction",
        "namespace": "com.mycompany",
        "doc": "Transaction records",
        "fields": [

        {
                "name": "version",
                "type": "int",
                "default": 1,
                "doc": "version the class"
        },
        {
                "name": "eventType",
                "type": "string",
                "default": "saleTransaction",
                "doc": "event type"
        },
        {
                "name": "writeTimestamp",
                "type": "org.joda.time.DateTime",
                "doc": "Timestamp when this event was written to the stream"
        },
        {
                "name": "originatingClient",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "identifier of the originating client"
        }
}
```

When I compile it using avro-maven-plugin, I get the following error:

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>
> Execution transaction-schemas of goal
>   org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.8.0:schema failed:
>   "org.joda.time.DateTime" is not a defined name. The type of the
>   "writeTimestamp" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...}
>   expression. -> [Help 1]

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no date support as of now in Avro, you would have to store the time as a long. And there is no support for custom types, as that would mean to support avro serialization and deserialization of that type.

Comment: ah, of course. deserialization is the issue. got it.